# How to share React Components between projects

Tags: reactjs, npm

I built a Component that I want to use in separate projects.  What is the simplest best way to reuse this Component across projects using NPM?

Answer (score 9):

You haven't indicated whether you wish to keep this component private, so I'm going to answer two ways:

### If you are going to open-source your component

This is easiest: publish your component(s) as an `npm` package (see the docs [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages)). Then install your package just like any other in the projects where you will be using your components.

### If you wish to keep it private

You have several options here:

1. pay for a private modules on `npm` ([docs here](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro)). If you go this route, you can install your package just like any other.
2. Use `npm link` ([docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)) to create a link from the project(s) to the component package located on your local storage. This works but is kind of tricky to set up. The benefit of this is that if you rebuild your component, all projects with a link to the component will see those changes immediately.
3. Use `npm install` to install from your (private) Github or other repository. This works similarly to the normal `npm install` and is a little easier to use than `npm link`. The downside is that any changes to the component need to be pushed to the remote repository and then the project(s) using the component need to be updated.

Comment: What about running `npm link`?  it creates a `tgz` file which, if i `npm install that.tgz` I will get my package in node_modules.

Comment: i also have a problem of getting es6 and jsx code in the imported package.  should i have webpack transpile the component to es5 before doing any of these options?

Comment: babel or webpack with targetModule: umd

Comment: I found lib https://github.com/OrKoN/npm-link-shared which installs a set of local node modules into a target folder using npm link